# Create a pgagent job with pgAdmin

Tags: database, postgresql, scheduler, pgadmin

Why pgAdmin creates a new pgAgent job only on the Postgres db even though I specify the setting on another db?

Answer (score 1):

Because the administration of pgAgent is stored inside the schema pgagent in the database "postgres". This has nothing to do with the database where the job will be executed.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. What I meant is that the job is executed only if the attribute "jstdbname" of "pgagent.pga_jobstep" (in the postgres db) is set to 'postgres' and not if it is set on the db that we are interested

Comment: That could be a permission problem. Does the user that executes the job, have the correct permissions? Check the database logfiles.

Comment: I solved it. The problem was that when I started pgagent, didn't set the "dbname = postgres" but as our db.

Comment: Thanks @teosantoro your comment saved me!